# exception caught syntax error rails button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am getting syntaxt error in the below code.

Can someone help me out here.

```
  <%= button_tag :class => 'pull-right margin-clear btn btn-sm btn-default-transparent btn-animated notify-class', :type => :submit,
      :id =>"notify-class<%=product.master.id%>" :style=>'display:none'    
      :data-toggle => "modal" , :data-target => "#myModal" >         
        Notify me!<i class="fa fa-bell" style ="margin-left: 10px;"></i>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: What syntax error are you getting?

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' ...@output_buffer.safe_append='" :style=>\'display:none\' \'d... ... ^ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing commas before :style and before :data-toggle - here is the corrected code:

```
<%= button_tag :class => 'pull-right margin-clear btn btn-sm btn-default-transparent btn-animated notify-class', :type => :submit,
      :id =>"notify-class<%=product.master.id%>", :style=>'display:none',    
      :data-toggle => "modal" , :data-target => "#myModal" >         
        Notify me!<i class="fa fa-bell" style ="margin-left: 10px;"></i>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need a `do` at the end of your `button_tag`:

```
<%= button_tag :class => 'pull-right margin-clear btn btn-sm btn-default-transparent btn-animated notify-class', :type => :submit,
  :id =>"notify-class<%=product.master.id%>" :style=>'display:none'    
  :data-toggle => "modal", :data-target => "#myModal" do %>         
    Notify me! <i class="fa fa-bell" style ="margin-left: 10px;"></i>
```

Second, you'll need to fix `"notify-class<%=product.master.id%>"`. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here, but you're injecting a `<%= %>` ERB tag within an existing <%= %> for your `button_tag`. If you're trying to interpolate a string, use: `"notify-class#{product.master.id}"`, which will work as long as `product` is defined.